# Renaming a single file in bash is removing the file after crashing script

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote this simple script to rename files who's name was too long to rename in the GUI. I was pointed to a couple of resources which have been helpful.  Currently, if you crash out or close the terminal window after dragging the source file in and hitting return, the source file disappears from the source directory. The deleting of the source file only happens when I isolate the file extension `${ext}` to use as a variable in the renaming.  But where does the source file go?  And why? It is not in the Trash.

When I rename the file and add the extension as user input, and crash out of the shell the source file remains in the source directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo
echo "NB ONLY HIT 'CTRL+C' TO CANCEL SCRIPT   "
echo "        DO NOT CLOSE WINDOW             "
echo "OTHERWISE THE SOURCE FILE WILL DISAPPEAR"
echo
echo "DRAG THE FILE HERE TO RENAME HERE AND HIT ENTER: "
echo
#does "IFS= read -r file" go here? 
read file
DIR=$(dirname "${file}")
fullpath="${file%.*}"
file2="${fullpath##*/}"
ext="${file##*.}"
echo
echo "Full path = ${fullpath}"
echo "Directory = ${DIR}"
echo "File name = ${file2}"
echo "extension = ${ext}"
echo
echo "ENTER THE NEW NAME WITHOUT THE EXTENSION: "${ext}" "
echo
#does "IFS= read -r new" go here? 
read new
mv -- "${file}" "${DIR}/${new}.${ext}" #THIS DELETES THE SOURCE FILE FOR SOME REASON
#mv -- "${file}" "${DIR}/${new}"  #THIS DOES NOT DELETE THE SOURCE FILE, MANUALLY ADD EXTENSION
echo
if [ -e "${DIR}/${new}.${ext}" ]
    then 
        echo "====================================================">&2
        echo "FILE RENAMED SUCCESSFULLY TO "${new}.${ext}"">&2
        echo "====================================================">&2
    else 
        echo "======================================">&2
        echo "         FILE RENAMING FAILED         ">&2
        echo "======================================">&2
fi
exit
```

I was advised to add `--` to the `mv` to stop file that start with a dash being interpreted as a switch.  Also added `>&2` to the echos in `if/else` statement so that  diagnostic logs to go to stderr where they belong by POSIX-defined convention (copy and pasted from his advise).

A third thing was said to me was to add `IFS= read -r file` and `IFS= read -r new` to help with leading and trailing white spaces but I am not sure where?  Would it be just before each `read`.  I have tested the current script and it accepts both leading and trailing white spaces, also backslashes.  It fails if forward slashes are used the `new` name but accepts them in the source `file` name. `IFS` is like `delims` in batch I think.  Why would I want/need for read input functions? [This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is the reference that was used for `IFS`

Comment: Why don't you do it in two steps instead? Copy the source file to its new destination and, if success, remove the file on the source directory.

Comment: `#does "IFS= read -r new" go here?` yes

Comment: @accdias because I'm just trying to rename it,  not actually move it to a new destination.  I read ```mv``` was the command to do this in bash.  @KamilCuk why would a field separator be needed here?  In my mind field separation is for interpreting columns of data, i but it is used for something different here.

Comment: `mv` is the equivalent of `rename` only, and only if you are leaving the file on the same directory it is before and after the `mv`. If you're `mv`ing it to another directory then it is obviously not just renaming. Check your code. You ARE moving files around and not just renaming them.

Comment: @accdias  I echoed out the ```mv -- "${file}" "${DIR}/${new}.${ext}"``` line.  It says it is the same directory.  I used ```dirname``` to purposefully use the same directory. Maybe I am not understanding correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Stopping the terminal may result in the file being renamed to ".ext", making it look as if the files was remove.

Long answer:

There is no information on the full environment (which terminal, ssh, etc.) that trigger the problem - I'm not able to actually replicate with closing the terminal, as described by OP. Was able to replicate with other input.

Per O/P, the problem occurs when the terminal is closed, while waiting for `read new`. While closing the terminal should result in HUP delivered to all processes, it is possible that the the PTY will be closed a little bit before the shell script get the HUP signal, especially on loaded system, when remoting via ssh, etc.

In this case, the `read new` will terminate with error. However, the code does not perform any check on new. As a result, the script will rename the original file to '.ext' (ext is whatever the original extension of the file). Since dot-files are not displayed in "ls", it will look as if the file was removed.

This can be simulated by entering the file name, and just clicking `enter` to the second prompt. For me, a file aa.txt, was renamed to `.txt`, making it look as if it was removed.

Consider adding minor check against this condition.

```
echo
echo "ENTER THE NEW NAME WITHOUT THE EXTENSION: "${ext}" "
echo
#does "IFS= read -r new" go here? 
if !read new ; then
   echo "Read Failed, aborting"
   exit 1
fi
if [ -z "$new" ] then
   echo "No name, aborting"
   exit 1
fi
```

You may also implement more restriction on the new name, as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  This stopped the deleting/removing behavior.  I had to add it in after ```read new``` which makes sense as the variable is not defined before.  It will never echo the lines though.  It either renames, or when crashed, not delete the file.  What exactly is happening here?  ```if [ -z "$new" ] ``` looks like it's a string comparison.  I can 't find any information on ```if !read```.

Comment: The ‘if !read’ check for EOF, and other error conditions. I am not sure what do you mean ‘crash’. What is the error message. Try running with -x to get more info, if needed.